# bash variables within variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, tokenize

I wrote a little bash script to make a "shell" that prints the date before and after a command is executed:

```
 while true
 do date
 printf "Prompt: "
 read x
 date
 $x        #Solution: this should be eval "$x"
 done
```

The problem is that this "shell" doesn't recognize variables in $x, so for instance `echo $PWD` outputs `$PWD` instead of the current directory.  A related consequence is that `cd` does not work.  How to fix/work around this?  Thanks.

EDIT: Solved.  Thanks everyone :-)

LATE EDIT: Actually the above isn't quite the solution; I needed to add the `-r` option to the `read` command, to prevent backslash sequences from being prematurely evaluated.  Furthermore, the double quotes appear to be superfluous after all in this case (since the prepass would expand `$x` and `"$x"` to the same thing unless `$x` is empty, and `eval` does the same thing with no argument as it does with an empty string), but I suppose it never hurts to always include the quotes as a matter of security and good style.

Comment: perhaps you want to `eval "$x"`? but... why?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  Because I want to print the date before and after every command without having to actually type `date; <command>; date` every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're just trying to print out the date before and after, you can do that with `PROMPT_COMMAND="$(date)"` in your `.bashrc`. This will print out the date before your command prompt (meaning that it will also functionally be after your command since you'll get a prompt after the command finishes). It will be on a separate line from your `PS1`, but you could add this to your `PS1` instead if you'd rather it be there.

If you're trying to type in a literal `echo $PWD` and have `x` give the value of that, you can do `eval "$x"` but most people will recommend against using `eval` because anyone can type anything, like `sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root`

If you're trying to set x to be the name of a variable, i.e., `x=PWD`, and you want to get the value of `PWD`, you can do `${!x}`. This is called "indirection".

Comment: The first suggestion only prints the date after the command; it does not account for the time the prompt sits there waiting for the command.  As for the last, I have x set to be the entire command line, not just the variable name.  `eval` seems like it works, but I'm curious as to how it can be dangerous.  Can't anyone _already_ type "eval sudo ..." on a regular command line?

Comment: @TravisKidd, correct. If you have bash >=4.4, you can use `PS0` to do things immediately before your command executes. You can also just `time cmd` to get the actual time a command takes. And yes, eval is just as dangerous as giving whoever input the command access to your command line, no more or less.

Comment: So without the root password, `eval` can't be used to wipe my filesystem, correct?  At any rate, it appears not to work after all.  While `echo $PWD` does print the directory, `PWD=/new/directory` still doesn't change it.  $PS0 looks promising, but I don't have bash 4.4 yet.

Comment: they could input `alias sudo='\sudo rm -rf / --no-preserve-root && echo "gotcha" &&'` so that the next time you used sudo and input your password, you'd wipe your own filesystem (pretty sure, I didn't test it). `PWD` is not for changing directories. `x="cd /new/directory"; eval "$x"` will work.

Comment: I think the best way to think about the danger of `eval` here is that you're giving the user access to the shell, which allows them to do ... any dangerous thing that they could normally do with access to a shell. The usual problem with `eval` is that it allows things you wouldn't expect to be executed -- like parts of filenames -- to be executed as commands ([obligatory xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)). In this case, you *expect* whatever's typed in to be executed as a command, so it shouldn't be a surprise when  it can be used destructively.

Comment: BTW, +1 for properly quoting the variable reference. I keep seeing things like `eval $x` (note the lack of double-quotes), which is broken and wrong in any situation I can think of.

Comment: OK, in my script I had the output of the command piped into `more`; turns out removing that made the difference, and now it works.  I'm just a little confused now as to the relationship between `PWD`and `cd` ... it seems `cd` changes the value of `PWD` as well as the working directory, but changing PWD directly does not change the working directory.  And yes thanks for the double quotes; better to correct that now than to have it blow up on me later.

Comment: @TravisKidd, bash has variables that tell you things, but do not influence the actual commands. `PWD` is one example, `DIRSTACK` is another (used with `pushd`). You are explicitly allowed to screw with these variables if you want, but doing so will not change the thing they are supposed to reference, and is generally not recommended